# Best way to find character at specific index in a compressed String

Tags: java

I know that we can do this by following ways

1. StringBuilder
2. Use substring

But i am looking a way where i have a compressed String say `a5b4c2` etc which means `a` is 5 times `b` is 4 times etc so String is actually `aaaaabbbbcc` something like that.

So char at index 2 should return a and char at index 6 should return b.

What can be the best approach for this?

*My question is more about what is the best approach to decompress String ?*

Comment: If your question isn't about finding the character at a specific index, then it's too vague to really answer clearly, to be honest... it's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @JonSkeet He wants the best approach. ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet: i m more interested about the approach to decompress String.Thanks for the pointer about question clarity,have updated it

Comment: It's still unclear, to be honest. Are you looking for a different class, or actually starting with a compressed string representation, or what?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is more about handling this compressed string rather than finding the character at specific index.

Decompress the string until you get the index you want to know.  Or you could decompress the whole string and cache it.

> What can be the best approach for this?

Without any more specific requirements, I believe the best approach is the simplest approach you can think of.

---

I would, parse each pair of the letter and the number in turn, reduce the index by that number and if the remaining index is < 0 you have the letter you want.

Comment: my question is more about decompressing the string? like what is best way to do it. i have updated the question.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi The best way to do it is the simplest and the most obvious way you can think of.

Comment: Agree with you about the simplest way to parse and add numbers +1

Answer (score 0):

Check what index you are searching for, and start adding up the numbers of characters. Every time you add, check if the index falls within the previous interval and the current one. If it does, you've found what your character is, otherwise add again.

For example, the workflow given your string `a5b4c2`, if you want the character at index 7, could be like this:

```
   current position: 0
   index we are looking for: 7
   add first character's count: 0+5 = 5
   does 7 fall within 0 and 5? no, add again
   current position: 5
   add second character's count: 5+4 = 9
   does 7 fall within 5 and 9? yes, so our character must be 'b'.
```

I'm not sure if this is more efficient or faster than decompressing the string and just using `charAt()` or something, it's just a different way of approaching it.

EDIT: Since the question is more about how to decompress the string, you could use a `StringBuilder` and use a `for` loop to append the correct number of the character to your string... sounds like the simplest way to me.